# Identification of the elements of a list - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, list

I've been trying lately to produce a list which will be containing two types of elements : the categories first, and then the classic products.
I've succeeded to display the list but the problem is that i want to determine whether the user clics on a category or a simple product to be able to do the right display after that.

the list is diaplyed like that :

I use a function to run through my result of my MySQL request and display the lines

```
while($row = $cursor->fetchObject()) {
  echo '<style> width: 500px </style><option value="'.$row->id.'" ';

  if ($row->id == $selected_id) {
    echo 'selected="selected" ';
  }
  if ($row->category_name != null) {
    echo '>' . $row->category_name . '</option>';
  }
  else {
    echo '>'.$row->name.'</option>';
  }
}
```

which's circled with  balises in the page.

Comment: may be you need to use ajax.. this will help you ..http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: The only way I can think of, if you are not using Javascript at all, is to add some prefix or suffix to the values, like `value="cat_MyCategor"` and then use `substr()` on the next page to determine if it's a category or product. Anyway I think using a select box might not be the most suitable option here. Maybe you should just produce a list of links, pointing to different URL's depending if they are category or products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more informations in the value, for example if it's a category or a name

```
while($row = $cursor->fetchObject()) {
        $content = '';
        $id = '';
        $selected = '';
        if ($row->category_name != null) {
            $content = $row->category_name;
            $id = 'cat_'.$row->id.'_'.$row->category_name;
        }else{
            $content = $row->name;
            $id = 'name_'.$row->id.'_'.$row->category_name;
        }
        if ($row->id == $selected_id) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected" ';
        }
        echo '<style> width: 500px </style><option value="'.$id.'" '.$selected.'>'.$content.'</option>';
    }
```

Then when you analysis the results, you can extract the ID and the format (category or name) thanks to explode for example

```
$temp = explode('_',$value);
$id = $temp[1];
if ($temp[0] == 'cat'){
    //here category
    $catname = $temp[2];
}else{
    //here name
    $name = $temp[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exaclty what I was looking for :)